# I can't use sbt.Process inside /src?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm currently using sbt to build and run my scala programs. I'm trying to use sbt.Process to execute system commands. I must be missing something because when I try to import sbt.Process in one of my files in src/ I get this error.

```
not found: value sbt
[error] import sbt.Process._
```

So it looks like I can't access the sbt package inside my src/ files. What do I need to do to access it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SBT's environment (v 0.7.x) is only available in your build file or a Plugin.

The easiest way to use sbt.Process library (until 0.9.x which will have Process as an independent library) is to copy (BSD License) [Process.scala](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/blob/0.9/util/process/Process.scala) and [ProcessImpl.scala](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/blob/0.9/util/process/ProcessImpl.scala) into your project

Comment: It would be better to use the src in https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/tree/0.9/util/process/ instead. That version should be the standalone version you can plug into the project. The ones you linked had dependencies on various sbt Logger libraries.

Comment: @Mrbuubuu: Agreed. I Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are different classpaths for running sbt and compiling your source files. 
One classpath is for compilation of files in directory project/build (that one contains sbt jars and usually scala library 2.7.7) and the other one is for building source files of your project (that one contains your dependencies from lib and lib_managed and usually scala library 2.8.*). If you'd like to use sbt.Process in your source files you can do two things:

- add sbt jar to lib or lib_managed for it to be available on your project's classpath
- use snapshot version of scala 2.9, it would have sbt Process built-in as sys.process package

Comment: SBT has a lot of dependencies and is built with Scala (v2.7.7) It would be easier to just copy Processs.scala and ProcessImpl.scala into your project

Answer (score 1):

Wait for Scala 2.9, and then just use it out of `scala.sys.process`.

Answer (score 0):

sbt package has became an integral part of the Scala standard library since version 2.9

> ...this API has been included in the Scala standard library for version 2.9.
>
> #### quoted from sbt wiki

Here's [the link](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Index) (scroll down)

well, in order to use it, all you have to do (assuming you are using sbt for build), is to add in `build.sbt` file the following line of code: `sbtPlugin := true` it will add the needed dependencies to your project.

of course, this solution is only to get your imports with `sbt` package to work. you should refactor your code to use the new package `scala.sys.process` like Daniel C. Sobral suggested.